# EventListener click function firing multiple times after initialize again during infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

This is my first question, so i try to describe it precisely as possible and follow the stackoverflow guideline "How do I ask a good question?"

My Problem:

Im using the "old but gold" [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) jQuery plugin to load the next posts on a wordpress site. Im also using the [lazyframe](https://github.com/viktorbergehall/lazyframe) plugin to load youtube videos "lazy" with a click on the play button of a video. To ensure the lazyframe function after loading a set of new posts with the infinte scroll function, im initializing the lazyframe in the following way with adding the `lazyframe('.lazyframe');` initializing code to the `function(newElements)` part of the infinite-scroll js:

```
    //infinite scroll
    if ($masonry.length && obj_testsite.infinitescroll != 'disable') {
    nextSelector = obj_testsite.nextselector;
    if (document.URL.indexOf('/source/') != -1) {
        nextSelector = '#navigation #navigation-next a';
    }

    $masonry.infinitescroll({
        navSelector : '#navigation',
        nextSelector : nextSelector,
        itemSelector : '.thumb',
        prefill: true,
        bufferPx : 500,
        loading: {
            msgText: '', // load spinner icon instead of gif images - see below
            finishedMsg: obj_testsite.__allitemsloaded,
            img: '',
            finished: function() {}
        }
    }, function(newElements) {

            lazyframe('.lazyframe');

            var $newElems = $(newElements);
            $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
            $masonry.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);                                  
    });
}
```

So far, this works fine. BUT, when i scroll down and load a few set of posts with infinite-scroll and then click the the play button sometimes the lazyframe plugin creates multiple youtube iframes.

My research so far showed me, that the reason why the event is firing multiple times is, because the event is attached to the element multiple times. The following code shows the part where the lazyframe plugin uses the addEventListener function to target an element in a document:

```
            function n(e) {
            if (e instanceof HTMLElement != !1) {
                var t = {
                    el: e,
                    settings: i(e)
                };
                t.el.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    return t.el.appendChild(t.iframe)
                }), d.videolazyload ? l(t) : s(t, !!t.settings.thumbnail)
            }
        }
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? I tried to stop the event propagation, but i was not able to fix it because of lack of knowledge. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you didn't set 'click' event via jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin author here. Thanks for using it!

There was a bug in the plugin that would attach multiple event listeners on the element/elements upon reinitialization. That's sorted in v1.1.1 so just update the plugin and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You use event capturing in your eventListener. Actually, not all browsers support event capturing (for example, Internet Explorer versions less than 9 don't) but all do support event bubbling, which is why it is the phase used to bind handlers to events in all cross-browser abstractions, jQuery's included.

The nearest to what you are looking for in jQuery is using on().
So you can change your code to this (event):

```
$(t.el).off('click').on('click', function() {
                    return t.el.appendChild(t.iframe)
                });
```

off() function remove event listener (in our case 'click') on element that you specified, so you can try this solution.

Comment: Dont work Nedim, half of the page is gone. Please have a look at the full code https://github.com/viktorbergehall/lazyframe/blob/master/dist/lazyframe.min.js

Comment: Wait, this click listener is in plugin, not in your code?

Comment: no - with plugin i mean the github code - not a wp plugin. i put the code manually in my custom js file.

Comment: Can you please paste some code on fiddle and make that issue that I can really figure out what is going on?